# function working on linear map is differential

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given that $f:L(V,W) \times L(U,V) \to L(U,W)$ where $L(V,W)$ are the linear transformation from vector space $V$ to vector space $W$ ,given that $f(A,b) = A B$,  prove that $f$ is differential and compute $Df$ ?

$f(A+G,B+H) = (A+G)(B+H) = A B +A H + G B + G H = f(A,B) + A H+ G B + G H$

i think that $AH + GB$ is the differential or because $G H$ is not linear but not quite sure, any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is your definition of differential? Maybe you mean differentiable instead?

Comment: @Masacroso yes that is what i meant

Comment: then $f$ is a bilinear function. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986732/langle-ft-gt-rangle-langle-ft-gt-rangle-langle-ft-gt-rang)

Comment: @Masacroso i still don't have a clue to weather my approach is good, can i say that $Df(A,B) (G,H) = A H + G B$ ?

Comment: what approach? What you wrote, by itself, is hard to understand what it mean or to what you are pointing. But yes, we have that $D f(A,B)(G,H)=f(A,H)+f(G,B)=AH+GB$